# Android - positioning TextView in layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-relativelayout

I don't know how I can set the TextView on the right side in my RelativeLayout. Adding gravity to the TextView didn't work. Thanks for helping me.

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); // center in linearLayout_power_stations_bar

    textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(nuke_count));
    textView.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.game_powerStationsBar_textOverIcon));
    textView.setTextSize(16);

    relativeLayout.addView(textView); // TextView over image
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView); // adding image

    linearLayout_power_stations_bar.addView(relativeLayout); // adding to other layout
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this layout in Java rather than in XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout parameters to TextView and also set alignment of parent right.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textViewsetLayoutParams(params);
```

Now You can Use this code :)

Comment: Can you please provide more details such as code examples or links to the documentation?

Comment: Now I'm update my answer according to your requirement :)

Comment: Ah, now I understanding my problem. Your code works fine thanks, but the problem in my case is, that the parent of the parent layout has a huge width and with ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT it will set up the TextView to the first parent layout (FrameLayout).

I have FrameLayout (huge width) --> LinearLayout (orientation vertical) --> RelativeLayout (contents text and img) --> TextView and ImageView.

Now the TextView set up on the right side in the FrameLayout, but it should be set up on the right side of the Linear or RelativeLayout, so the TextView is over the ImageView.

Comment: @David Your layout would be easier to understand with a screenshot and/or mockup that illustrates it. Better yet, give us the XML for your layout.